# Smooth submanifold of $\mathbb R^6$. Not smooth submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

So I'm pretty new to studying manifolds and have little to no background on differential geometry, but this is a question from lecture notes on a multivariable analysis unit:

> Show that $S:=\{(x^2,y^2,z^2,yz,xz,xy)|x,y,z \in \mathbb R, x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$ is a smooth 2-submanifold of $\mathbb R^6$ and show that the projection of $S$ onto the last three coordinates (The Roman Surface $R:=\{(yz,xz,xy)|x,y,z \in \mathbb R, x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$) is not a smooth 2-submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$

For the first part I tried to construct an atlas for $S$, given by:

$\phi_1: D \to S$, where D is the open unit disc around the origin in $\mathbb R^2$, such that $$(x,y) \mapsto (x^2,y^2,1-x^2-y^2,y\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2},x\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2},xy)$$
and $\phi_2$ and $\phi_3$ are defined similarly by isolating $x$ and $y$, respectively, on $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$

Now what I would like to know is:

1) Is this enough to show that $S$ is a smooth 2-submanifold of $\mathbb R^6$?

2) If the answer to 1) is yes, then, is this generally the best way to prove that a subset is a submanifold?

3) For the second part I have no idea how to show something is not a submanifold and would appreciate any help on the matter

Comment: Can you link to the lecture notes?

Comment: @symplectomorphic  I could, but they are extremely confusing and also not in english

Comment: I'm also interested in these notes. I can also read in Spanish, Portuguese and French. If it is on any of those languages, could you still post it?

Comment: Here goes the link to the lecture notes, I must add that they are incomplete since it's an ongoing unit, and is updated somewhat regularly: https://www.ime.unicamp.br/~joa/U-CAMP/ENSINO/2019-1-MAMM720-AnaRn/analise2.pdf

Comment: I should also say that the notes are in Portuguese

Comment: When applying on the cases $x=0,\ y=0$ and $z=0$, separately, we can see that the neighborhood of the origin in $R$ contains segments from *all 3 axes*, however the tangent space of $R$ at any point should be 2 dimensional..

Comment: @Berci I see it now, thanks for the tip!